# How to color an edge in a graph as a certain color

Tags: python, sage

I want to plot a graph in Sage with edges colored differently
according to whether they meet a certain condition. Nothing in
the documentation I have read so far has information on
coloring a specific edge of a graph.

I do not know what function could do this, but I have set
the code up, which I will show:

```
for edge in g.edges()
    if edge[2] == -1:
        edge = ? # not sure how to change color of the edge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting different edges in different colors is built into Sage!

See the `edge_color` and `edge_colors` optional arguments of the `plot` method
of graphs listed in the table of graph plotting options in the
["Graph plotting" page of the SageMath reference manual](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_plot.html)
and the example there that says "This example shows off the coloring of edges".

See also the examples illustrating
[the `set_edges` method of graphs](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_plot.html#sage.graphs.graph_plot.GraphPlot.set_edges).

To illustrate one way to achieve the requested coloring,
start from the Petersen graph and label the edges by
1 if they join vertices of different parity, and by -1 otherwise.

```
sage: g = graphs.PetersenGraph()
sage: for u, v, c in g.edge_iterator():
....:     g.set_edge_label(u, v, (u - v) % 2 - (u - v + 1) % 2)
....:
```

Observe the result:

```
sage: g.edges()
[(0, 1, 1),
 (0, 4, -1),
 (0, 5, 1),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (1, 6, 1),
 (2, 3, 1),
 (2, 7, 1),
 (3, 4, 1),
 (3, 8, 1),
 (4, 9, 1),
 (5, 7, -1),
 (5, 8, 1),
 (6, 8, -1),
 (6, 9, 1),
 (7, 9, -1)]
```

To plot the edges blue or red accordingly:

```
sage: red_edges = [e for e in g.edge_iterator() if e[2] == -1]
sage: g.plot(edge_color='blue', edge_colors={'red': red_edges})
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 26 graphics primitives
```

[image: Petersen graph colored by parity]

One could also have done:

```
sage: blue_edges = [e for e in g.edge_iterator() if e[2] != -1]
sage: red_edges = [e for e in g.edge_iterator() if e[2] == -1]
sage: g.plot(edge_colors={'blue': blue_edges, 'red': red_edges})
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 26 graphics primitives
```

---

The rest of this answer explains how we could do this by hand:
create a subgraph for each edge color, and then plot these subgraphs together.

To illustrate this, start from the Petersen graph, and color edges
differently depending on whether they are between vertices of same parity.

```
sage: g = graphs.PetersenGraph()

sage: a = copy(g)  # edges between vertices of different parity
sage: b = copy(g)  # edges between vertices of same parity

sage: for u, v, c in g.edge_iterator():
....:     if (u - v) % 2:
....:         b.delete_edge(u, v)
....:     else:
....:         a.delete_edge(u, v)

sage: pa = a.plot(axes=False, edge_color='blue')
sage: pb = b.plot(axes=False, edge_color='red')
sage: p = pa + pb
sage: p.show()
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 37 graphics primitives
```

[image: Petersen graph colored by parity]

To save the plot:

```
sage: p.save('Petersen_graph_by_parity.png')
```

For the original problem, use `if c == -1` instead of
`if (u - v) % 2` to decide whether to delete the edge from `b` or from `a`.
Also, the Petersen graph comes with vertex positions already set,
which might not be true of the graph `g` in the question,
in which case replace the two lines defining `pa` and `pb` by:

```
sage: pa = a.plot(axes=False, edge_color='blue', save_pos=True)
sage: pb = b.plot(axes=False, edge_color='red', pos=pa.get_pos())
```

This answer is inspired by
[Thierry Monteil's answer](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/43872/?answer=43874#post-id-43874)
to a similar question:

- [Ask Sage question 43872: Plot a graph with some edges dotted](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/43872)